# Capture command's output without translating "\n" to literal newline

Tags: bash, shell

`cat file.json` gives me what I want to capture inside of `$JSON`:

```
{ 
  key: "value\nwith\nnewline\nchars"
}
```

I can't do `JSON=$(cat file.json)` though because then the newline characters are translated and I get after `echo $JSON` or `echo -e $JSON`.

```
{
 key: "value
with
newline
chars"
}.
```

How can I preserve the newline characters inside of `$JSON`?

Comment: No, they aren't translated on capture/assignment. How are you *displaying* the value of the variable? More likely it's translating them on display, and the capture is actually fine.

Comment: Try `printf '%s\n' "$JSON"` to display the `JSON` variable's value accurately. (**Do not** use `printf "$JSON\n"`, and `echo` may or may not be reliable depending on runtime configuration).

Comment: Right -- don't use `echo -e`; that *explicitly tells* `echo` (when in bash's default standard-noncompliant mode) to replace `\n` with a literal newline.

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451742/14122

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! Go ahead and give an answer and the glorious 10 points will await you

Comment: I was literally staring at the answer when I gave up :| https://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples. I think my brain is full for the day.

Comment: BTW, the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture using command substitution doesn't perform the translation you're worried about here, but using `echo` (or misusing `printf` by substituting into the format string rather than a separate parameter) *will*.

---

To emit a variable with backslash sequences intact, use:

```
printf '%s\n' "$JSON"
```

This avoids behavior that `echo` can have (either explicitly with bash's noncompliant extension for `echo -e`, or implicitly when the `xpg_echo` flag is enabled in bash, or as default out-of-the-box behavior with other, POSIX+XSI-compatible `/bin/sh` implementations) wherein escape sequences are replaced by `echo`, even if the variable passed as an argument had a multi-character backslash sequence.